# How do I check if a list-value from my Map is empty?

Tags: apex, list, map, exception, queryexception

I get this error in case if `Opportunity__c` has no `OpportunityInfo__c`. I try to check it with the condition `if(opportunitiesMap.get(actualTool.Rent__r.Opportunity__c).OpportunityInfo__r != null)`, but it doesn't work. How can I check it correctly? I would be grateful for the code examples.

```
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Rent__c rent : allRents){
        oppIds.add(rent.Opportunity__c);
    }
    Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunitiesMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
        [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id, Status__c FROM Rents__r WHERE Check_in_date__c >=: Date.TODAY()),
        (SELECT Id, Bag_color__c FROM OpportunityInfo__r) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : oppIds]
    );   
    List<Tool__c> actualTools = [SELECT Id, Rent__r.Opportunity__c FROM Tool__c
                                 WHERE Rent__r.Opportunity__c IN : oppIds AND Check_out_date__c >=: Date.TODAY()];

    for(Tool__c actualTool: actualTools){
        List<Rent__c> neededRents = opportunitiesMap.get(actualTool.Rent__r.Opportunity__c).Rents__r;
        OpportunityInfo__c oinf = new OpportunityInfo__c();
        if(opportunitiesMap.get(actualTool.Rent__r.Opportunity__c).OpportunityInfo__r != null){
            //'System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject' is here:
            oinf = opportunitiesMap.get(actualTool.Rent__r.Opportunity__c).OpportunityInfo__r;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use isEmpty() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the list empty value, You can use these methods from List class:-

1. [isEmpty()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm)

Returns true if the list has zero elements. Example:-

```
!opportunitiesMap.get(actualTool.Rent__r.Opportunity__c).OpportunityInfo__r.isEmpty()
```

2. [size()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm)

Returns the number of elements in the list. Example:-

```
List<Integer> myList = new List<Integer>();
Integer size = myList.size();
system.assertEquals(0, size);

List<Integer> myList2 = new Integer[6];
Integer size2 = myList2.size();
system.assertEquals(6, size2);
```

**List!=null** will be true till the time you have not initialized it.Let see this example:-

```
List<Account> acclist1;
List<Account> acclist2 =new List<Account>();
system.debug(acclist1);
system.debug(acclist2);
```

When you execute it, You get null for acclist1 and empty list for acclist2.

[image]